# Sorting out questions with unspecific titles or question scope

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, editing

The purpose of this meta post is to gather vague questions titled along the lines of "need help with a sentence" or "translation help", and figure out if they're plain translation requests or proofreading requests or if they have generated useful discussion.

We should decide if the question needs to be:

- Edited (either in the title or in the main body) to reflect what it is actually asking
- Closed
- Left as it is

It may help in getting answers for the question if the question's scope is identified correctly. Also, being able to identify the question from the title would make it easier for potential answerers to participate.

---

These questions will be gathered in the answer to this meta post to give them more visibility and access to the community.

Please edit the list below to include questions or to remove questions that have been edited.

Answer (score 2):

## Character recognition requests

- [What's this handwritten character?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23870/whats-this-handwritten-character)
- [Can't recognize these handwritten kana (or kanji) in a text](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19149/cant-recognize-these-handwritten-kana-or-kanji-in-a-text)
- [Few hard to recognize handwritten characters in miniature umbrella](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17687/few-hard-to-recognize-handwritten-characters-in-miniature-umbrella)
- [Can anybody tell me what this means?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14965/can-anybody-tell-me-what-this-means)
- [Help identifying a low-res kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14442/help-identifying-a-low-res-kanji)
  [I have no idea what my old shirt says. Can anyone help?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4872/i-have-no-idea-what-my-old-shirt-says-can-anyone-help)
- [What is this kanji? 「兵」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13549/what-is-this-kanji-%E5%85%B5)
- [Can't find this kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24840/cant-find-this-kanji)
- [How to read this kanji? (see image)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14383/how-to-read-this-kanji-see-image)
- [Help identifying low-res kanji (and perhaps words) on a low-res album cover](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15660/help-identifying-low-res-kanji-and-perhaps-words-on-a-low-res-album-cover)
- [Can someone please help me identify the first kanji in the image?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24999/can-someone-please-help-me-identify-the-first-kanji-in-the-image)
- [What kind of kanji is this?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24836/what-kind-of-kanji-is-this)
- [How do I look up this kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-do-i-look-up-this-kanji)
- [recognize kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17679/recognize-kanji)
- [How to read this kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28110/how-to-read-this-kanji)
- [Recognizing these kanji: a counter with a circle at the top; and "【?】に" (looks like 大 at the bottom)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17594/recognizing-these-kanji-a-counter-with-a-circle-at-the-top-and-%e3%81%ab-looks-l)
- [Recognizing this kanji: ホイールが【?】いよく回転](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17585/recognizing-this-kanji-%e3%83%9b%e3%82%a4%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%8c-%e3%81%84%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e5%9b%9e%e8%bb%a2)
- [What is this kanji? It's too small for me to understand right now](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13674/what-is-this-kanji-its-too-small-for-me-to-understand-right-now)
- [Kanji identification?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13032/kanji-identification)

#### Seems useful:

- [What is this kanji ? Looks like 七 three times](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21226/what-is-this-kanji-looks-like-%E4%B8%83-three-times)
- [What is this strange kanji that looks a bit like 侍, but isn't?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23851/what-is-this-strange-kanji-that-looks-a-bit-like-%e4%be%8d-but-isnt)
- [What is this character that looks like 人? Is it some kind of quote?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13557/what-is-this-character-that-looks-like-%e4%ba%ba-is-it-some-kind-of-quote)

Answer (score 1):

More Questions With Vague Titles:

[I need help with an example sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29621/i-need-help-with-an-example-sentence)

[Help with understanding a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30357/help-with-understanding-a-sentence)

[Help with this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33903/help-with-this-sentence)

[Help deconstructing a paragraph](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32733/help-deconstructing-a-paragraph)

[Trouble understanding sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33765/trouble-understanding-sentence)

[So I am reading through a text and I am not sure if my translation of this sentence is correct](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32601/so-i-am-reading-through-a-text-and-i-am-not-sure-if-my-translation-of-this-sente)

[Subject tracing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32773/subject-tracing)

[Meaning of sentence in dialogue](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33142/meaning-of-sentence-in-dialogue)

[Strange question/answer pattern](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33220/strange-question-answer-pattern)

[Is this sentence structured correctly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33655/is-this-sentence-structured-correctly)

[Can someone please help me understand the structure of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33626/can-someone-please-help-me-understand-the-structure-of-this-sentence)

[Confusing sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32567/confusing-sentence)

[Help understanding this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32540/help-understanding-this-sentence)